# Java getColumLabel and getColumnName not working correctly

Tags: java

I have this query:

```
select a.id AS testid, b.id as test2id from connector a LEFT JOIN connector_status b ON a.id = b.id where a.id = 99999
```

I want to retrieve metadata from the resultset with this code:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.setMaxRows(1);
ResultSet rs  = st.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = meta.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + meta.getColumnName(i));
    System.out.println("Label: " + meta.getColumnLabel(i));
}
```

I get this result:

```
Name: testid
Label: testid
Name: test2id
Label: test2id
```

What am I doing wrong? getColumnName() should return id, or am I wrong?

Best regards
Peter

Comment: What dbms are you on? See some information about on JDBC implementation of getColumnName and getColumnLabel http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel(int).

Comment: PostgreSQL, but the query should work for every dbms

Comment: There are differences between implementations :/ see for example h2 http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#column_names_incorrect .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a.id is aliased as testid. Because otherwise "id" would be ambiguous in `select a.id AS testid, b.id as test2id from connector a LEFT JOIN connector_status b ON a.id = b.id where a.id = 99999`.

The getColumnName() returns "testid" because of the alias "testid".